# Network Error when attemting to fetch resource

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I try to do a request to an API, but sometimes request is not done and the error message is:

TypeError: Network Error when attemting to fetch resource.

[image]

I checked by two browser chrome and firefox.

[image]

Here i attached some screenshot of the desktop.

[image]

I lookforward to hear any solutions.

Thank you.

Some lines of the code to manage request and response:

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    salone
      .get(`/attestati/verifypassword?contentId=${this.props.id}&password=${this.state.psw}`, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}`,
          "content-type": "application/json",
        },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({
          changePas: response?.data.detail,
        })
        console.log(this.state.changePas);
      })

      .catch((error) => {
        // window.open(error.response?.data.detail)
        console.log(error.response?.data.msg);
        this.setState({ changePas: error.response?.data.msg })
      })
}
```

and onPSWChange function:

```
onPSWChange(event) {
    this.setState({ psw: event.target.value })
  }
```

Here is the submit form, in render we put it:

```
<div><Form method="get" id="contact-form" onSubmit={(e) => this.handleSubmit(e)} >
          <label htmlFor="PSW" contentEditable="true" ></label>
          <textarea type="text" style={{ height: "38px", resize: "none" }} placeholder="inserisci password" className="form-control" onChange={this.onPSWChange} />
          <button type="submit" className="button blue-btn w-100">Invia</button>
 </Form></div>
```

Comment: You need to wirte some code, examples, where your API is etc. Notice that noone knows your project

Comment: Thank you, i wrote some lines of the code.

Comment: You need to test this API using httpie or PostMan, never test your API with frontend